# How to read contents of specific page from PDF using itextsharp APIs

Tags: pdf, c#-2.0, itext

How to read contents of specific page from PDF using itextsharp APIs

Can anybody redirect me to the correct direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "contents of specific page" do you mean the page's text, or the page's actual Content Stream.

Answer (score 1):

The following code only extracts text, if that is what you are looking for.

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(documentPath);

ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

//Extract text from the page.
string txt = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, its);

// Convert the extracted text into a readable string using the right encoding.
extractedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txt)));
```