# Pull specific text from pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am creating a program that, at the moment, is using locationtextextractionstrategy() from iTextSharp to retrieve the text inside a pdf. This works great except for how long it takes for some of the pdfs I have to run through the program. So I was curious if there was a way to only pull a certain amount of text from a pdf instead of pulling it all. Maybe use coordinates to specify a region and then extract the text from the specified area. Any input would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What about this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421766/how-to-read-contents-of-specific-page-from-pdf-using-itextsharp-apis

Comment: I think it depends on you deciding how to finalise the fetching process from PDF. You can either give the number of pages, lines or sentences. Here is a [link](http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/parsing-pdfs-part-1-itext-5/) about iText 5 you may want to check it. Since it is Java code, it only helps about theoretical part of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. That is what I am already using. locationtextextractionstrategy is very similar to simpletextExtractionstrategy and I have been switching between both. What I would like to know is that if there is something in iText where I can maybe specify a region a pull the text from that region instead of pulling all the text from the page. And I will check that out right now, thanks coner!

Comment: Look at `RegionTextRenderFilter`, you can find a [Java example of using it here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=279)

Comment: As @Chris pointed out, you can filter the text pieces which eventually are forwarded to your extraction strategy. Unfortunately, though, I doubt that this will speed up matters much because the main work - the *parsing* of the content streams and keeping track of states and everything - still is done for the whole page.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful advise! One quick little question for you guys. Does the page content have an effect on the speed? say i did a text extraction on a blank page compared to one with more text, would the blank page go through faster or do they all get rendered at the same rate?

Comment: I would say that in general, the more "stuff" that's on a page the longer it will take. However, "longer" could mean milliseconds or seconds. I would also say that in general, a PDF made programmatically via a library such as iText will probably parse faster than a PDF made from a desktop-based GUI program like Adobe InDesign. Desktop programs allow designers to tweak a lot of things and in order to realize these tweaks in a PDF the syntax tends to get very complicated.